# Disproving uniform continuity for a couple functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have two functions that others seem to view as trivially nonuniformly continuous but it is not immediately apparent to me why.
Here is the first: $f_n(x)$ is defined on $[0,1]$. Define the function as increasing linearly to one on the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2n}]$ decreasing linearly back to zero on the interval $[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}]$, and zero from $[\frac{1}{n},1]$. It is clear to me that this should converge pointwise to zero, but I am not sure why the convergence isn't uniform. It seems that the convergence is not dependent on the $x$ value and would hence be uniform.
The second function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as $0$ from negative infinity to $n$. Then linearly increasing to 1 on the interval $[n,n+1]$, and $1$ from $n+1$ to positive infinity. This seems to also converge pointwise to 0, but i cannot again see why this isn't uniform convergence. Also, are both functions equicontinuous, and how would I prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the zero function.

Then $|f_n(\frac{1}{2n})-f(\frac{1}{2n})|=1$ for all $n$.

We do not have $|f_n(\frac{1}{2n})-f(\frac{1}{2n})| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ !

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these sequences of functions converge uniformly to $0$, because for that to be true you would need their supremum to converge to $0$. But $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)=1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Could I modify the triangular function such that it would be uniformly continuous on all compact sets but not on R